# Google Actions click tracking

Tags: google-schemas

Does the Google Actions [google-schemas] provide any tracking/analytics to clicks? I can track these clicks on the processing (URL) page, but I was wondering if there was anything built-in.

Answer (score 0):

No, no specific tracking/analytics is provided with Google Actions.